# KNOWNFOLDERID for C:\Program Files in 32bit app on 64bit OS

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

According to the [`KNOWNFOLDERID` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457.aspx), it seems to be saying that a 32-bit app cannot retrieve the 64-bit `C:\Program Files` folder path.

I have a 32-bit app and need the known folder for `C:\Program Files`, not `C:\Program Files (x86)`.

I have tried to disable WOW64 and this does not help.

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: *"I have tried to disable WOW64"* - You cannot *"disable"* WoW64. If you run a 32-bit application on a 64-bit OS, it naturally must run in the emulation layer. What have you really tried?

Comment: @IInspectable probably tried to disable WOW64's file system redirector instead.

Comment: you can get *ProgramFiles* folder by `GetEnvironmentVariable` [`ProgramW6432`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384274(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`GetEnvironmentVariable()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getenvironmentvariable) to read the `%ProgramW6432%` variable according to Microsoft article [WOW64 Implementation Details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinProg64/wow64-implementation-details):

> Environment Variables
>
> When a 32-bit process is created by a 64-bit process, or when a 64-bit process is created by a 32-bit process, WOW64 sets the environment variables for the created process as shown in the following table.
>
> ---
>
> 64-bit process
>
> PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64 or PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=IA64
>
> **ProgramFiles=%ProgramFiles%**
>
> **ProgramW6432=%ProgramFiles%**
>
> CommonProgramFiles=%CommonProgramFiles%
>
> CommonProgramW6432=%CommonProgramFiles%
>
> Windows Server 2008, Windows Vista, Windows Server 2003, and Windows XP:  The ProgramW6432 and CommonProgramW6432 environment variables were added starting with Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2.
>
> ---
>
> 32-bit process
>
> PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=x86
>
> PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432=%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%
>
> **ProgramFiles=%ProgramFiles(x86)%**
>
> **ProgramW6432=%ProgramFiles%**
>
> CommonProgramFiles=%CommonProgramFiles(x86)%
>
> CommonProgramW6432=%CommonProgramFiles%

So, `%ProgramFiles%` will point to either the 32-bit or 64-bit folder depending on the architecture of the calling app, but on a 64-bit OS `%ProgramW6432%` will always point to the 64-bit folder in both architectures.